# Hangfire context constructor injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

I tried following IHttpContextAccessor pattern but for Hangfire context. What I'm mostly interested in is CustomScope class with Resolve method. I'm using ActivatorUtilities there because otherwise I would need to register TestJob to IServiceCollection, this way it resolves without the need to register it.

Snippet is for .NET 6

Is there a better way to do this?

```
using Hangfire;

var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {        
        services.AddScoped<IUser, User>();
        services.AddScoped<IHangfireContext, HangfireContext>();
        services.AddTransient<CustomJobActivator>();

        services.AddHangfire((provider, configuration) =>
        {

            configuration.UseActivator(provider.GetService<CustomJobActivator>()!);
            configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("server=.;database=Hangfire;trusted_connection=True;");
        });

        services.AddHangfireServer();
    })
    .Build();

var background = host.Services.GetService<IBackgroundJobClient>();
background.Enqueue<TestJob>(x => x.Run());

await host.RunAsync();

public class TestJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestJob> _logger;
    private readonly IUser _user;

    public TestJob(ILogger<TestJob> logger, IUser user)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _user = user;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Job run for id {job} job name {name}", _user.Id, _user.Name);
    }
}

public interface IUser
{
    public string Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class User : IUser
{
    public User(IHangfireContext hangfireContext)
    {
        Id = hangfireContext.JobActivatorContext?.BackgroundJob.Id ?? "-";
        Name = hangfireContext.JobActivatorContext?.BackgroundJob.Job.Type.Name ?? "-";
    }

    public string Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }
}

public class CustomJobActivator : JobActivator
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CustomJobActivator(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public override object ActivateJob(Type jobType)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService(jobType)!;
    }

    public override JobActivatorScope BeginScope(JobActivatorContext context)
    {
        return new CustomScope(_serviceProvider.CreateScope(), context);
    }
}

public class CustomScope : JobActivatorScope
{
    private readonly IServiceScope _serviceScope;

    public CustomScope(IServiceScope serviceScope, JobActivatorContext context)
    {
        _serviceScope = serviceScope;

        var hangfireContext = _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHangfireContext>();
        hangfireContext.JobActivatorContext = context;
    }

    public override object Resolve(Type type)
    {
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(_serviceScope.ServiceProvider, type);
    }

    public override void DisposeScope()
    {
        _serviceScope.Dispose();
    }
}

public class HangfireContext : IHangfireContext
{
    public JobActivatorContext? JobActivatorContext { get; set; }
}

public interface IHangfireContext
{
    JobActivatorContext? JobActivatorContext { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My bad, was looking for .net tags and in the end I forgot C# tag

Comment: refer this : https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html, Also, you could use `Autofac` extension, it would make things easier.

Comment: I'm trying to do it with default DI container. I mean this works, I'm just wondering if I missed something